# How to call a method in HTML other than (click)="method()"

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Calling a GET request to wordpress api. How would i display the data as the page loads in an ionic app using angular.

I can get my desired post list, but only when i use a(click) on a button to call the method in the HTML. I have done a course on Udemy, and this is my first attempt at building an ionic app with angular so i may have not even needed the method?

HTML

```
<ion-content>

  <button (click)="onGetPosts()">Get Posts</button>
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <ion-title>
        {{ post.title.rendered }}
      </ion-title>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

for-sale.page.ts

```
export class ForSalePage implements OnInit {

  posts: any;

  constructor(private saleService: ForSaleService) { }


  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onGetPosts() {
    this.saleService.getPosts()
      .subscribe(
        (posts: any) => this.posts = posts,
      );

  }
}
```

for-sale.service.ts

```
export class ForSaleService {

  posts: any;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPosts() {
    return this.posts = this.http.get('http://***/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');

  }

}
```

So it is retrieving a list of posts as expected when clicking the button then string interpolation in the *NgFor for the required data. But I can only load the data in the first place at the click of a button.

**What id like, is for all the data to be loaded as soon as the page is opened.**

I suspect I may have not required a method? As this is the only page this data is required but I couldn't figure out any other way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method in ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.onGetPosts()
}
```

Comment: Oh wow of course. Thankyou very much. I actually tried to use OnInit, but i put the whole onGetPosts() code, never even thought of doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks):

With this hooks you can execute code to different lifetimes of the component.

In your case OnInit shoud work.

```
  import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  export class ForSalePage implements OnInit {

  posts: any;

  constructor(private saleService: ForSaleService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.saleService.getPosts()
      .subscribe(
        (posts: any) => this.posts = posts,
      );
  }

}
```